# cannot resolve org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config

Tags: gradle, spring-cloud-config

I am using gradle to build and here is my build.gradle

Is there anything that I am missing in the gradle file

> ```
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
>     maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
>     maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot" }     
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
> apply plugin: 'java'
> apply plugin: 'javac2'
> apply plugin: 'docker'
>
> dependencies {
>    compile project(':services')
>    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
>    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
>    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
>    compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0'
>    runtime 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver'
>
>    testCompile 'junit:junit'
>    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
>    testRuntime "com.jayway.awaitility:awaitility:$awaitilityVersion"
>    testRuntime 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path'
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'java'
>
> springBoot {
> executable = true
> }
>
> dependencyManagement {
> imports {
> mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
> }
> }
>
> docker {
> baseImage "java:8"
> }
>
> task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
> applicationName = "ldp-data-fetcher"
> exposePort(8080)
> addFile("${buildDir}/libs/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar", "/opt/jmg/app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")
> }
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.8
> targetCompatibility = 1.8
> ```

Answer (score 5):

The first answer is correct or you can explicitly define dependency management and versions as follows:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.9'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.5")
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-config-server'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

```
dependencies { 
  [...]
  compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version: '2.0.1.RELEASE'
}
```

instead of:

```
compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2021.x.x")
}
```

springCloudVersion not specified, adding this extension in root of file worked for me